# Error received when using an API get request with json and python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Im getting an error when i try to do an API get request. Im new so I don't know much and I keep getting an error. The info for the api is here: https://github.com/aravindasiva/demotivational-quotes-api and the API im using is this https://demotivation-quotes-api.herokuapp.com/graphql
The API responce is in a json array and Im trying to pull specific information from that. Any help is appreciated.

```
import requests
import json

def get_quote():
  response = requests.get('https://demotivation-quotes-api.herokuapp.com/graphql')
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  quote = json_data[0]['quote'] + " -" + json_data[0]['author']
  return(quote)


quote = get_quote()
print(quote)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    quote = get_quote()
  File "main.py", line 6, in get_quote
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: do repr(response.text) or print("{}".format(response.text)) and u will see the issue.
I am not a pythonist, maybe a straight print(response.text) would also work

Comment: When I try each of those solutions, i get the same error:  Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 12, in <module> print(response.text) NameError: name 'response' is not defined

Comment: You kind of found the issue ... there is no such thing as response.text . Now use the same approach on response and see what u have

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

After looking further into your problem I've spotted your issue. The api you're attempting to use is expecting a post request, not a get request. It is then expecting a payload containing a query for the api in order to find you the quotes you're looking for.

You want to be using the `requests.post()` method.

This should be enough to point you in the right direction, I would recommend looking up some tutorials on how to use `requests` and the differences with the different HTTP methods.

---

I think your problem is that your response contains no text data. Perhaps it returns a json instead? Try printing your response json like so

```
print(response.json())
```

You also may want to try directly printing `response.text` to confirm it's a `None`.

Verify the response before you try to parse it into your `json.loads` method.

edit:

Try this

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://demotivation-quotes-api.herokuapp.com/graphql')

print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

Comment: I tried your new solution and I got this as a response: 400
<bound method Response.json of <Response [400]>> What should I do next?

Comment: See my edit. What exactly is it you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get the information from the site, and format it to print in such a way that it shows as the quote and then the author.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're saying. Do you have any idea on how to set up the post request?